# Is it true printf takes first two assignment as input

Tags: c

i read somewhere that
printf takes the values of the first two assignments of the program. Any
number of printf's may be given. All of them take only the first two
values. If more number of assignments given in the program,then printf
will take garbage values.

i don't think so but it was given on many websites so just need to confirm it

For example, if you do a simple Google search for `"printf takes first two assignment as input"` there are sites that have sample interview question/answers such as:

> Predict the output or error(s) for the following:

```
main()
{
    int i=400,j=300;
    printf("%d..%d");
}
```

> Answer: 400..300
>
> Explanation: printf takes the values of the first two assignments of the program. Any number of printf's may be given.
>
> All of them take only the first two values. If more number of
>   assignments given in the program,then printf will take garbage values.

Is this the correct true behavior? or is it implementation dependent?

You can find such Q&A places like:
[this puzzle site](http://www.c-puzzles.thiyagaraaj.com/puzzles-a.html)
and [this interview question doc](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.utdallas.edu%2F~veerasam%2Fc_c%2B%2B%2Fweb-download%2FC%2520Interview%2520Questions.docx&ei=S4v1UNHPLsW30AG1sIGICQ&usg=AFQjCNFtT_n5za1F6TX4ggEHK9wzpe56ig&sig2=4_lHjKaaOZZQ_mcgfjoKuQ)

Comment: What are you talking about? Care to share an example?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're asking... if you've seen it on "many" websites, can you provide an example?

Comment: please give us some code snippet which explains your problem

Comment: Maybe he means local variables on the stack are picked up by `printf()` as varargs parameters, or something. Who knows.

Comment: OK, I google searched part of your question `printf takes first two assignment as input` and came up with several interview questions to that effect. I think I see what you're saying and I think it's worth asking so I'm going to update your question for you and vote to reopen.

Comment: @GrahamBorland: That was my interpretation as well (that or picking up something in a couple of registers).  In which case, the answer is "no"; it's possible that this is one of the many possible results of calling `printf` without any parameters, the behavior of which is *undefined*.  I'm curious to see these many websites, and have...*a polite discussion* (yeah, that's it) with their authors.

Comment: `printf("%d..%d");` - Its an undefined behaviour. Not all compiler will print first two initialised local variable`s value.

Comment: Googled using the same phrase as Mike, and found what I think the OP is talking about.  The code is `int i = 400, j = 300; printf("%d...%d");`, and per that site the expected result is "400...300".  The behavior on passing fewer arguments than what is expected in the format string is *undefined*; the result *may* be "400...300", or it may be garbage, or the program may crash.  So the short answer is, "**NO**, this is *not* true except by accident on some specific implementation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's definitely not true.

For the context, read C11 7.21.6.3/2:

> The `printf` function is equivalent to `fprintf` with the argument `stdout` interposed
>   before the arguments to printf.

So, from the standard, C11 7.21.6.1/2:

> The `fprintf` function writes output to the stream pointed to by stream, under control
>   of the string pointed to by format that specifies how subsequent arguments are
>   converted for output. **If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.** [...]

(emphasis mine)

What can possibly happen is that the values from the stack may be pulled by `printf()` when it's called. Then again, since behavior is undefined, anything could happen, from printing garbage values or a program crash, to printing out a cake picture on the neighbor's parallel printer (really, [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908924/492901)).

Unless your *specific* implementation (a *specific* CPU architecture, with a *specific* compiler and possibly a *specific* operating system) *documents the specific case* as being something you can do, **don't do it**.

Your puzzle site's "puzzles" are mostly a combination of undefined behavior and incorrect assumptions regarding implementation-defined behavior. Some examples are correct, but considering it's mostly bad, I'd just pretend I never saw it. Random internet sites tend to be a bad resource for learning programming, especially C. If you want to learn C, you should get a proper book on C programming (a list [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info)).

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the correct true behavior? or is it implementation dependent?

That is undefined behavior. There are no guarantees of what will happen at all.

A possible implementation of the ellipsis `...` mechanism in `C` may result in the particular evaluation that you show in your question, although it also depends on the compiler and optimizer.